# Thread.sleep() to swing Timer conversion

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, sleep

I am trying to implement a `Thread.sleep(6000)` line but it seems to freeze in the applet. When I tried to use Timers, I wasn't sure how to use because I am not very good with event listeners. I am basically trying to call a method `fetchUrl()` every 6 seconds, after the user clicks the enter button. How can I implement this?

```
public void init() {

    c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(flow);
    c.setBackground(forum); 

    question.setForeground(Color.white);
    question.setFont(tnr);  
    question2.setForeground(Color.white);
    question2.setFont(tnr);
    result.setForeground(Color.white);
    result.setFont(tnr);    
    resp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));
    timeLength.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));
    c.add(question);    
    c.add(resp);
    c.add(question2);
    c.add(timeLength);
    c.add(enter);
    c.add(result);
    resp.requestFocus();
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    t = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    t.setInitialDelay(DELAY);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    final String n1;
    int timeMin, timeSec, count = 0, maxCount;
    timeMin = Integer.parseInt(timeLength.getText());
    timeSec = timeMin * 60;
    maxCount = (int)(timeSec/6);
    if (e.getSource() == enter) {         //user clicks enter
        n1 = resp.getText();
        while (count < maxCount) {
            fetchUrl(n1);                 //this method called every 6 seconds
            t.start();
            count++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First I would start by separating the `ActionListener` for the `Timer` and for the `JButton`.

Second nothing is happening logically with the Timer because you're swallowing it with the button source check.

Third you should understand how the timer works. Basically for every *"tick"* (in your case six seconds) the `actionPerformed` of the timer ActionListener is called. So if you want the `fetch()` method called, then that's what you should be visible/accessible to the in the Timer's actionPerformed.

The button's `ActionListener` should only handle the starting of the timer I believe. So just separate the listeners. Give each one an anonymous `ActionListener` and no need to make the class implement `ActionListener`.

For example

```
timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do some stuff every six seconds
        fetchURL();
    }
});

enter = new JButton(...);
enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

If you want some automatic stopping feature for the timer, you could do something like

```
timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (someStoppingCondition()) {
            timer.stop();
        } else {
            // do some stuff every six seconds
            fetchURL();
        }
        // do some stuff every six second
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I get what you mean by the button absorbing the source. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a method after user clicks on button every 6 seconds, but you have not said how many times you want to call it.

For infinite number of times, try something like the following,

```
while(true){

     new Thread(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
                try{
                       Thread.sleep(6000);
                       fetchUrl(n1);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){}
          }

     }.start();

}
```

If you will use Thread.sleep() in your applet, then your applet will be hanged for 6 seconds and so create a new thread for it.